# How to know when geth --rpc is finished so i can start mining

Tags: go-ethereum, ethminer

i have Geth --rpc running but it seems that it is never-ending.

Do I have to wait for Geth to stop before i use ethminer?

thsnks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't need geth for ethminer at all.

> The ethminer is a command line program. This means you launch it
>   either from a Windows command prompt or Linux console, or create
>   shortcuts to predefined command lines using a Linux Bash script or
>   Windows batch/cmd file. For a full list of available command, please
>   run `ethminer --help`

From [source](https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer#ethminer).

And if you need account you can use something like metamask or myetherwallet to generate it, geth is not required for it.

Comment: If you are solo mining you will need ethereum node fully synchronized.